# How to disable bukkit server auto-disabling?

Tags: minecraft, bukkit

Hello I wanted to debug some of my bukkit plugins, but the problem is I can do brakepoint for max of 1 min, because after this time server auto-stops how can I disable it?

Comment: Bukkit have auto-shutdown system that automaticly close server if single server tick tookes over 60s. `A single server tick took 86,35 seconds (should be max 0,05)`

Comment: OP is pausing the process with a debugger. If you pause the main thread for too long, then the server exits itself with an error about a too-long tick as soon as you resume. I'm curious if there's a work-around too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Minecraft's server.properties](https://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Server.properties#Server.properties) defines how long a tick can be before shutting down

```
max-tick-time=60000
```

Increasing this should let you pause the tick for a longer period of time

The time is in ms, so for a 1 hour pause use 1*60*60*1000=3600000

```
max-tick-time=3600000
```

If you wish to disable the feature entirely, -1 can be used

```
max-tick-time=-1
```